# В $.post -> .donate принимает success/fail и пр. параметры. Как?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Здравствуйте. Есть следующий код (копаюсь сейчас в одном из js файлов):

```
$.post(app.login.handler_url, data)
.done(function(response) {

    if(response.success) {
        location.href = app.login.next_url;
        return;
    }

    if(response.error) {

        if(response.error == "incorrect credentials")
            if(app.login.need)
                app.show_notification('Ошибка!', 'Логин, пароль или другие данные неверны.');
            else
                app.show_notification('Ошибка!', 'Неправильный логин или пароль.');
        if(response.error == "You've reached request limit.")
            app.show_notification('Ошибка!', 'Превышен лимит запросов.');
        return;
    }

})
```

У меня вот вопрос, как образом можно сформировать ответ на сервере, чтобы после отправки ($.post), вызвался .done а в нем response.error или response.success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть сервер отдает вам объект или ассоциативный массив в JSON.
Ответ будет такой например(PHP):

```
$response = [
    'error' => false, 
    'success'=>'content'
]; 
return json_encode($response);
```

А в js вам нужно сделать `response = JSON.parse(response)`